# generate geoJSON perfect hexagon all over the earth

Tags: javascript, geospatial, geojson

Hye, Im trying to generate a geoJSON with perfect hexagon that will cover all earth with no overlap but right now I did not found a way to generate automatically. So far I use

https://github.com/node-geojson/geojson-random

can anyone pointed me out or any suggestion ?

something like this :-

[image]

Thank you!